# Too much scrolling with Big Cartel site. Could someone help me with the css?

Tags: css, bigcartel

This site http://doomedfromdayonemerch.bigcartel.com/ is currently scrolling too much down the page, this is because the footer (hidden) is at the bottom of the page. Even when i move the footer with CSS the page still scrolls the same amount. would like it to ideally to only scroll down a little bit. I did have overflow-y:hidden on the body, and although this did work, it doesn't allow for smaller screens/zooming in, as you then cannot scroll at all. Any help would be great! :)

Comment: Ypou've got heights set on wrap and main. These may not be required - try removing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **CSS** code add

```
html{
    height:100%
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! that was so simple! it's always the way with CSS!

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with footer.

The problem resides in your div id="navigation"

I did some questions related to sticking footer into bottom of page. Check them out, maybe will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know an answer has been selected but let me explain a little further.  You have the navigation div positioned relative, instead of absolute.  It looks like you were trying to use absolute positioning because I see z-index in the navigation css.  To use absolute positioning the parent element needs to be set to position: relative; and the element you want to have absolute needs to be set to position: absolute;

add position relative to #wrap

```
#wrap {
width: 740px;
height: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 5px;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
}
```

and change navigation to absolute

```
#navigation {
z-index: 99;
position: absolute;
top: 175px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 5px;
margin-right: 4px;
height: 442px;
background: rgba(228, 228, 228, 0);
clear: both;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
right: 10px;
}
```